# Font reset to default upon Installation - C#

Tags: c#

I installed my application to the client's PC. Upon execution I noticed the changed in the fonts I used on the software. It resets to default that makes the program interface looks bad. While troubleshooting this issue, I discovered that the font I used (Century Gothic) doesn't exist on their system.

I tried to download/install 'Century Gothic'. But still nothing happened. What is the solution on this problem?

Comment: You can include the fonts to your installer, and set the installer to install-copy the fonts into the client machine before installing the software...set some flag in the registry or something...

Comment: I have tried that already but still.. no result. One thing I noticed that there is no .NET Framework installed on their PC. Do you think it might be the possible solution if I installed the latest Framework?

Comment: The .Net Framework doesn't include fonts. Also, unless you have a license that allows it you can't (legally) distribute a font with an application. The installer your are using determines how to include a font in your application's install, e.g. for MSI you can add the Fonts special folder and include the font file there.

Comment: Note that font filename conflicts could mean you damage the client's PC permanently installing a font. You can restrict yourself to the integrated Windows fonts or include the font in your application and load it into Windows from your application folder or resource and then use it.